# Cant produce histogram, x must be numeric

Tags: r, histogram

```
data = read.csv("studentheights.csv",header=T)
hist(data$Heights)
```

not sure where I got it wrong

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nicolas Cheah, could you please provide us some reproducible data using `dput(data)` so that we can help you further?

Comment: The error message means that R doesn't think that `Heights` is a number, but something else. If you run `class(data$Heights)` you can see what class it is. If it is character/factor it is probably some issues with the data import, e.g. that your file use other decimal marks than `.`, or that some rows contains strange values. It's impossible to say for sure without some reproducible data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your height value are not `numeric`. I created a reproducible example, so if you run the following code it would probably work:

```
data <- data.frame(Heights = c(148.7, 168.4, 161.5, 174.7, 165, 167.8, 168, 164.9, 170.6, 170.7, 157.3, 170.2, 166.2))
hist(as.numeric(data$Heights))
```

Output:

[image]